# Regex should find substring that does not start with /

Tags: regex

I want to find version numbers in a long string.
Example: "Hellothisisastring 12.3 blabla"

I need to find a substring that is a version number but does not start with "/".

Example: "Hellothisisastring /12.3 blabla"
shouldn't match.

I already build following regex:
[0-9]+.[0-9]

How can I detect a that the version number does not start with "/". The problem is that it is not at the beginning of the string. I already tried with negative lookahead.

(?!/)[0-9]+.[0-9] still matches with a slash before.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: So, `(?<![\d\/])[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a lookbehind and include a digit pattern to also fail the positions right after digits:

```php
(?<![\d\/])[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wl2KNj/1/%5D).
Also, you may match any amount of `.` + digits using

```php
(?<![\d\/])[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wl2KNj/2). *Details*:

- `(?<![\d\/])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit or `/` immediately to the left of the current location
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.[0-9]+)+` - one or more sequences of a `.` and one or more digits.

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot. How could I check if a slash is afterwards?

Comment: @KongKonfus With a `(?![\/\d])` negative lookahead.

Comment: @KongKonfus Did it finally work?